# Regular expression validation, must follow format 1-xxxxxx and not #1-xxxxxx

Tags: regex, string-matching

I am trying to use regular expressions to validate a data entry. I am very new to this field, so please bear with me.

An ID number of the form 1-xxxxx must be entered. It always begins with a 1, then a -, then followed by 1-6 characters

I was able to validate it correctly assuming the user entered it WITHOUT a # using
    1-.*

Now, I would like the function to keep ensuring that the user enters the number as 1-xxxxxx but ALSO be erroneous if they add in the # character. Using
    [^#]1-.* 
does not give me the desired result, because it will now only be erroneous if there is a #, and ignores the other conditions. Im used to boolean, and tried [^#|1-.*] but clearly this is bad syntax. PLEASE HELP :D

Comment: Will `^1-\w{1,6}$` work for you?

Comment: @anubhava we are unsure if the underscore is allowed or not.  It seems like the OP just wants letters and numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have it not include the `#` before your `1`, you can try `^1-[\da-zA-Z]{1,6}$`.  This also adds an extra little bit on your 1 to 6 chars. clause you want.  This simply restricts the regex to starting and ending, and not allowing partial pieces inside larger strings.  Using the examples in your comments I did some testing [here](http://rubular.com/r/Mpscccb6dd).

By wrapping the regex in `^$` you make it so if it starts with anything besides a `1` it will break.  Breaking the regex apart you get:

1. `^`, start of the line
2. `1-`, the easy part you already figured out.  REQUIRES that the start of the string is a 1 DIRECTLY followed by `-`, nothing inbetween... no spaces, other things, etc.
3. `[\da-zA-Z]`, any digit or letter lowercase/capital a-z.
4. `{1,6}` repeat the last piece anywhere from 1 to 6 times.
5. `$` end of line.

Comment: Your right. IT MUST start with 1-xxxxx. So if there is a way to say if anything aside from a 1 and - is there, its wrong, that is good. Also, I am not too crazy as to start validating every kind of typo and random user nonsense that will go into the field. I will assume some minor level of intelligence from my user ;)

Comment: Without a lot more rules based on these "Legacy" IDs, the regex can get real tricky really fast.  Without providing ALL the rules, just saying any 5-6 chars works is not good.  You need some kind of restriction, or using an OR will validate your previous negative cases (`#1-1c1` for example) since that is a valid example of 6 chars in a row.  So without more strict rules, having just a blanket OR 5-6 chars will make a lot of false positives on bad data you were trying to stop initially with the orig. question.

Comment: @user2912577 I updated the answer to have all these new findings discuessed in the comments.  Consider moving the new rules and details up into the original question and deleting some of the comments to keep the question clean.  I did testing with the examples you provided, and gave a link in the post.  If this meets your needs, make sure to upvote and accept the answer so I can get a little reward for taking time to help :)

Comment: I cannot upvote you since I dont have 15 points, but I did checkmark the answer and thank you :D